# Correctness of proof based on nested interval theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am given that for positive integer n, let $a_n=1-(1/n)$ and $b_n=1+(1/n)$.  $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$.

I am to show that 1) the hypothesis of the nested interval theorem are satisfied, 2) find the point of intersection of these intervals and 3) Determine its sequential limits.

1) Confirm that the hypothesis of the nested interval theorem are satisfied.
Claim: $a_n<b_n$.  We have that 1-(1/n)<1+(1/n) => -1/n<1/n which is true since n is a positive integer

2) Confirm that $I_{n+1}$ is a subset of $I_n$ for every index n.
To do this do I just need to show that $a_n \leq a_{n+1} \leq b_{n+1} \leq b_n$?

3) Show that the limit, as n approaches infinity of [$a_n-b_n$] is equal to 0.
As a result I end up evaluating the limit of n tending to infinity of (2/n).
To show that ${1/n}$ tends to 0, let $\epsilon$>0.  We must find an N s.t. $|1/n-0|$<$\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.
By Archimedean Property we can select an N s.t. $1/n\leq 1/N$ < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.  Thus {1/n} converges  to 0 and by combination rules of limits the scalar of that limit must also tend to 0.

The next part involves finding the point of intersection for these intervals. How do you do that?  From what I see, since one interval overlaps the other shouldn't there be a few points of intersection?

Lastly, the sequential limits can be found by taking the limit as n approaches $\infinity$ of both $a_n$ and $b_n$ which both yield 1.  This is because the limit as n tends to infinity of a constant is that constant plus 0.

Please help me edit any mistakes I have and help me on the two parts I am unsure about.

Comment: The only common point is $1$, as a picture shows. To see explicitly that there cannot be a $\delta\ne 1$, pick $n\gt \frac{1}{|1-\delta|}$. But the general theorem takes care of uniqueness.  In your first part of the argument you wanted to prove that $a_n\lt b_n$ and "proved" it by deriving a true thing from the assumption that $a_n\lt b_n$. That is logically wrong, and must be fixed.

Comment: I don't think a picture would be good for a rigorous proof.  How might you show that?  I think I was just trying to verify the hypothesis in order to get the nested intervals to work.  If were doing that, then this step would be appropriate, right?

Comment: I am not sre what part of my comment you are referring to. If it is the proof that $a_n\lt b_n$, and you feel that proof is needed, to show $1-\frac{1}{n}\lt 1+\frac{1}{n}$ it is enough to show that $b_n-a_n\gt 0$. But $b_n-a_n=\frac{2}{n}$, which *is* $\gt 0$.